# Which SPARQL implementation (triplestore) is ideal for read performance?

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore

I'm new to RDf and I'm looking for an open source RDF databse, that has excellent read performance. There would be about 10 billion triples and 100+ SPARQL queries per second. Right now, I don't need to read and write to the database simaltaneously.

I've seen the databases enisted in wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL#SPARQL_implementations) but I'd like some expert advice on which is the most time tested system. It should have Apache license or an equally permissive license.

Answer (score 4):

Jena and Sesame are probably the only databases that fit your licensing criteria, but neither will scale to the size you need.  Jena with TDB *might*, but I'm not sure what the performance will be like at that scale.  Sesame Native certainly is not designed for that scale.

There are other open source databases, but they are GPLed, such as 4store, which might fit your performance criteria.  But your best bet is to use a commercial database (most have free evaluation versions); that's the best way to get the scale and read throughput you desire.  But that means you might have to actually pay someone for their hard work, bummer, I know.

Comment: "You might have to actually pay someone for their hard work" +1